# Magento has a redirect loop

Tags: magento

My Magento web site home page has a redirect loop error. When I try to open it it goes to my old server url and gives the error:

> The webpage resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer.

When I try to go into admin it takes to me old server admin url without any error.

I down loaded the fresh data base and connected my store to that it works fine but when i connect it my old data base it give same error.

Please advise me.

Answer (score 17):

This isn't an ideal solution, but I was having issues with Magento 1.9.x.

The setup was: `Nginx Proxy & SSL Terminator => Apache Webserver`

No matter what I did enabling SSL caused a redirection loop. I narrowed the issue down to Magento rather than the Nginx configurations.

It was like Magento didn't know it was receiving a secure connection from Nginx even though the correct headers were set.

The dirty solution was to add some code to the very bottom of `index.php` within the magento root directory (ie. `/var/www/magento`) just before the `Mage::run...` line, like so:

```
if( isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) ) {
    $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
    $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] = 443;
}

Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
```

Comment: this solution worked for me, while clearing the cache did not.

Comment: For those who are using AWS ELB needs to set this in Magento version 2.3.0 not sure why but the previous version I was using which is 2.2.0 not required this.

Answer (score 5):

Wrong permissions *can* also cause this to happen.  So in addition to truncating the `var/cache` and `var/session` folders, go ahead and make sure that you have the proper permissions on the `app`, `skin`, and `includes` directories, sub-directories and files.  I believe the suggested permission setting is **644**.  You can do this with a proper FTP client such as FireZilla.

Answer (score 3):

Go to table core_config_data

Update these value to be your localhost url(or whatever url you are providing while installation):

web/secure/base_url //(new url)

web/unsecure/base_url // (new url)

Empty the var folder.

Comment: Yes i did that but solved the problem when i manually deleted cache

Answer (score 1):

I got it fixed.

I manually deleted my cache i was unable to login in my amdin and it get fixed

Answer (score 0):

My issue was Cloudflare, put it in Development mode and it worked.  It was cache related.

Answer (score 0):

**Issue: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS - redirected you too many times**

This issue is related cookie domain name.

For ex: if you already installed Magento 2 in **www.example.com**, and now you change magento base path to sub domain path like **www.subdomain.example.com** means, then you need to update your cookie domain entry inside of **core_config_data** table. You cannot access magento 2 backend so you can use following query to check record exist else use insert query.

```
SELECT * FROM  `core_config_data` WHERE  `path` REGEXP  'cookie_domain'
```

if record exit then update **subdomain.example.com** to the value column.

else

```
INSERT INTO `core_config_data` (`scope`, `scope_id`, `path`, `value`) VALUES ('default', 0, 'web/cookie/cookie_domain', 'subdomain.example.com');
```

Then flush cache using command **php bin/magento cache:flush**

Refresh magento 2 admin, now you can access admin. try this. thanks.

Note: if you are not using cookie domain, then don't configure this settings, if you configuration wrong then also you can face this error, so to fix that error update value to default configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and after reloading and reloading my page I noticed that the error message responded to www.mydomain.tld and sometimes to mydomain.tld. I'm using Plesk on the server and I remembered that I set the Domain to always be called without www. I just changed that to none in the hosting settings of the domain. Lucky me, that solved that issue. Hope that helps someone else.