# Magento moved permanently error for home page only

Tags: php, magento, nginx, magento-1.9

I have a Magento Installation version 1.9.3.1. Until yesterday It was working fine, but now the frontpage is not working with the error - Too many redirects.

On further checking in the console(firebug), I can see all the files are showing as moved permanently as also it is adding a extra slash / that is two slash in the end of the sitename in the browser address. also in console all the get pages are showing as //

update:

I observed that it is only home-page/index.php where I am facing this issue. for example If I am accessing site/category-name it is working fine.

I tried to fix that using :

```
if(!$_SERVER['HTTPS'] || strtolower($_SERVER['HTTPS']) != 'on' ){
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
    header('Location: https://' . str_replace('www.','',$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    exit();
}
```

but that also didn't worked.

**Further Update:**

if I use `domain.com/index` or `domain.com/index.php/index` I am able to access the site without any 
`too many redirects error` or `moved permanently error`

Contents of relevant conf file:

```
server {
        listen 80;

        server_name www.sub.domain.com;
        #server_name sub.domain.com;
        #rewrite ^(.*) http://sub.domain.com$1 permanent;
}

server {
        listen 80 default;
        listen 443 ssl;
         server_name www.sub.domain.com;
          #ssl        on;
          #ssl_certificate         /key/domain.com.pem;
          #ssl_certificate_key     /key/domain.com.key;

        # access_log off;
        access_log /home/sub.domain.com/logs/access.log;
        # error_log off;
        error_log /home/sub.domain.com/logs/error.log;

        root /home/sub.domain.com/public_html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        server_name sub.domain.com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }
```

Comment: found these after google search: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35780097/magento-1-9-too-many-redirects  | https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/162443/magento-1-9-https-err-too-many-redirects/167633 | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16507584/magento-has-a-redirect-loop